# Prefixing variables names to indicate their respective scope or origin?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, scope, prefix, notation

In the companies I've been working, I've seen a lot the use of prefixes to indicate the scope or the origin of variables, for example `m` for classes members, `i` for methods intern variables and `a` (or `p`) for methods parameters:

```java
public class User {

    private String mUserName;

    public String setUserName(final String aUserName) {
        final String iUserName = "Mr " + aUserName;
        mUserName = iUserName;
    }

}
```

What do you think about it? Is it recommended (or precisely not)? I found it quite ugly in a first phase, but the more I use it, the more I find it quite convenient when working on big methods for example.

Please note that **I'm not talking about the Hungarian notation**, where prefixes indicate the type rather than the scope.

Comment: I don't like it, but maybe it can help others review code. BTW, there are a lot of mXXX in Android Source.

Comment: Personally extra prefixes signalling data types irritate me, especially when the data types get changed and the variables don't get refactored. A debugger will show you the data type. There is nothing worse than disinformation. Just stick to the normal Java conventions; CamelCase for class names, thisCase for function names etc.

Comment: I think in a team of more than 2 programmers it is quite useful to make every variable as understandable as possible. If I program on my own I wouldn't use it.

Comment: It looks ugly and it removes code readability, you can look at java coding conventions in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html but if it maintenance project you cannot change the existing conventions as it bring extra confusions :)

Comment: I think the issue is that your variable name is too generic to begin with. Nearly everything has a name so the scoping and reach issue comes to the fore. Much better would be to use `userName` as the instance variable. With properly qualified variable names, the overly general name no longer really needs a scope prefix.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just a side note: the prefixes here don't indicate the data types but the scope/origin of the variables, which is slightly different.

Comment: @BobDalgleish This was just an example, not a real *in-use* bean. But I've edited to make it clearer, thanks.

Comment: I have seen this practice of using a scoping prefix both in text books and some non-Java code. In both cases, as far as I was concerned, the prefix helped slightly because of weaknesses in creating the variable names. Java uses `this`as a scoping prefix, as in `this.mUserName`, to show the proper scope; I don't believe you need anything else when there is the possibility of confusion. On the other hand, if you are working on code for those companies, then you use their coding standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also worked in shops that had rigid prefix notation requirements, but after awhile this became a "smell" that the code had grown out-of-control and global variables were leaking from everywhere indicating poor code/review.

Java's "this." notation is the prefered way to reference a field, over a local.  The use of "m" prefix for variables was popularized by that "Micro.." company as a branding gimmick (they even said "don't use that because we do").

The general rule I follow is to name the variable according to what it is used to store.  The variable name is simply an alias.  If it stores a user name, then userName is valid.  If it is a list of user names, then userNames or userNameList is valid.  However, I avoid including the "type" in the variable-name now, because the type changes quite often (shouldn't a collection of user names be a set, in practice? and so on...)

At the end of the day, if the variable name is useful to you to remember what the code was doing down the road, it is probably a good idea.  Maintainability and Readability trump "perceived" efficiency and terse syntax, especially because modern compilers are rewriting your code according to macro usage patterns.

I hope this helps somewhat, and am happy to supply more details of any claims herein.

ps. I highly recommend the Elements of Java Style for these types of questions.  I used to work with the authors and they are geniuses when it comes to style!

Answer (score 0):

Note: yours is a very opinion-based question (generally frowned on in StackOverflow these days), but I still think it's a worthwhile topic.

So here's my perspective, for what it's worth:

Personally, I think an indicator of scope in variable names can be helpful, both when writing and reading code. Some examples:

- If I am reading a class method and I don't see any "m_XXX" being used, I can conclude "this function might as well be static — it doesn't use instance data." This can be done with a quick scan of variables, if the names have that information.
- Any time I see "g_XXX" (global), I can start being worried, and pay closer attention (: Especially writing to a global is a big red flag, and especially *especially* if there is any concurrency/threading involved.
- Speaking of concurrency, there is a pretty clear ordering of "safeness" for mutable data: locals are okay, members are dangerous, globals are *very* dangerous. So, when thinking about such code, having variable scope in mind is important. For this reason, in C/C++ I think having a prefix for function-static variables is useful, too (they're essentially "global" across invocations of that function). More an indication of lifetime than scope, in that case.
- It can help junior developers think about the above issues more actively.

The popularity of this convention varies by language. I see it in C++ and C most often. Java somewhat frequently. Not very much in Python, Perl, Bash or other "scripting" languages. I wonder if there is some correlation between "high performance" code and benefit from such a scheme. Maybe just historical happenstance, though. Also, some languages have syntax that already includes some of this info (such as Python's `self.xxx`).

I say disregard any arguments along the lines of "oh, Microsoft invented that for XYZ, ignore it" or "it looks clunky." I don't care who invented it or why or what it looks like, as long as it's useful (:

Side note: Some IDEs can give you scope information (by hovering your mouse, doing special highlighting, or otherwise), and I can understand that people using such systems find putting that info in the variable names redundant. If your whole team uses a standard environment like that, then great; maybe you don't need a naming scheme. Usually there is some variation across people though, or maybe your code review and diff tools don't offer similar features, so there are still often cases where putting the info inside the text itself is useful.

In an ideal world, we would have only small functions that don't use lots of variables, and the problem such naming prefixes try to solve would not exist (or be small enough to not warrant "corrupting" all your code with such a scheme just to improve some corner cases).
But we do not live in an ideal world.

Small functions are great, but sometimes that is not practical. Your algorithm may have inherent complexity that cannot be expressed succinctly in your language, or you may have other constraints (such as performance or available development time) that require you to write "ugly" code. For the above-mentioned reasons, a naming scheme can help in such cases, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Having variable naming convention works great for teams, and IMO must be used for languages that are not string typed. e.g. JScript.

In Jscript the only type is a ‘var’ which is basically evaluated at run-time. It becomes more important in Jscript to decorate the variables with the type of the data that is expected to be in them. Use consistent prefixes, that your team can decide,  e.g. s or str, or txt for string, i/j/l/l/m/n for integers ( like FORTRAN :-) ), q for double, obj or o for non primitive data etc. basically using common sense. Do not use variable names without any prefix unless the variable name clearly indicates the data type.

e.g.

variable name “answer” is a bad name since answer could be text, or a number, so it must be 
strAnswer or sAnswer , jAnswer, qAnswer etc.

But

“messageText” or "msgTxt" is a good enough because it is clear that the content is some text.

But naming a variable "dataResponse" or "context" is confusing.

Sometimes on the server one needs to fix or debug something and the only editors are vi or notepad in worst cases nano / sed, where there is no contextual help from the editor, having a coding convention can be really helpful.

Reading the code is also faster if the convention is followed. It is like having a prefix Mr. or Ms. to determine the gender. Mr.Pat or Ms.Pat... when Pat itself does not tell the gender of Patrick or Patricia...